# Which DAISY reader works on Android?

Tags: android, daisy

I want to have a DAISY book read for me on Android. Which reader works?

The DAISY book is on a micro SD card.

Comment: have a look at http://www.daisy.org/category/tools/mobile-applications

Comment: And also at [my list of eBook readers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_ebookreaders). To give good answers, we'd need more specifics: what features do you want, what is your price limit? Otherwise this ends up in a [list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), which is frowned upon on SE sites. // Two good candidates: [Kota Daisy Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.daisy.reader), [Talking Book](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbdaisy). Both well rated and seem maintained.

Comment: Kota Daisy Reader does not open my book, Talking Book does the job. You might want to set it as answer.

Comment: After 2 days of usage [I want to get rid of Talking Books](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171556/how-to-deinstall-talking-book). Why? Because it starts randomly and I cannot find it as application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Go Read](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.benetech.android) as it is gratis you haven't lost anything if it is not for you.